# Change Margins in ClassicThesis

Tags: margins, classicthesis

I am writing my thesis and using the excellent `classicthesis` package. My university has strict margin guidelines for submission (left = 1.5in, right = 1in, top = 1in, bottom = 1in).
I played around a little using the `areaset` command to modify the `textwidth` and was able to get the right margins after some iterations. But i was wondering if anyone could help me with an elegant way to do it so that I can replicate it in the future for other specifications.

Comment: I think that would defeat the purpose of using `classicthesis`, which is to emulate the layout of *The Elements of Typographic Style*. I would use `memoir` instead.

Comment: I understand. In fact I would be using the default settings when I publish my thesis on `Lulu`. But I need the settings to comply with university requirements.

Comment: try the geometry package

Answer (score 13):

Although, as others have said, this defeats the purpose of `classicthesis`, you can use the `geometry` package to setup whatever margins you wish:

```
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

Comment: Although this may help in overwrite the margin settings, I'm curious to find where/which part in the .sty files of the package classicthesis where the margin width is defined.

Comment: You can find it in the [source of classicthesis.sty](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/), starts near line 238. Apparently margin settings are chosen w.r.t. paper size and selected font.

Comment: This gives me a clash. It says: `The package geometry has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]
Adding the global options:
  ,left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.`

Comment: When I use geometry to adjust the margins, the chapter numbers are not affected and disappear.