# Combining tufte handout with classicthesis article

Tags: document-classes, classicthesis, tufte

I am a sucker for the large margins in Tufte-inspired classes, and in classicthesis. However, I want to write an article with a Tufte layout ([example](http://people.ucsc.edu/~weissman/MathClubTalk2009.pdf)), but with the classicthesis title/author/abstract/contents/(general front matter) structure. To me, the tufte-handout class is too 'handouty', and the tufte-book is too 'booky'. I want a genuinely 'articley' class.

For an example of the classicthesis part (in fact the article in question), see [this article](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1101/1101.2363v1.pdf) written by me. (Note to mathematicians: this is not the most up-to-date version! The content has been much improved since).

Perhaps the way to go about this is to hack classicthesis, so that the margins are as per tuftr-handout (e.g. as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22248)). Or perhaps hack tufte-handout so that the front matter is as per classicthesis (but left-aligned the tuft-handout front matter). However, I have no experience in this matter! Which would be better? Or is there another way?

Comment: Can you be more specific in which elements you'd like to use from classicthesis's front matter?  Do you prefer tufte-handout's headings or classicthesis's headings?  Which document class most resembles what you want your final document to look like?  That should be the base.  Then you can add the modifications on top of that.

Comment: Having looked at your papers cited above, my approach would be to use the tufte-handout as the base class. You will then need to overwrite the relevant formats for the title and headings. My suggestion would be to tone down a little bit the headings from classicthesis, as they can overwhelm the page. If you still interested in a solution just post a comment and I will offer some code as a reward for the egg-slicer idea in your paper (great concept)!

Comment: @Yiannis - the egg-slicer is not my idea; that is one of the standard tufte-handout examples from the tufte latex classes site.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides - well, I never really asked for the solution, but I'd still be interested...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also needed something with the same functionality as the `tufte-latex` class, but the option to configure the chapter and caption headings, the page layout and such differently. So I started writing the package [sidenotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes). It is in the middle of everything, there are no example files, yet, but the documentation is at least there.

It provides the macros/ environments `\sidenote`, `\sidecite`, `\sidecaption`, `sidefigure` and `sidetable` and a few helper macros. Please note, `\sidecite` only works with `biblatex`. Also, if you are used to `tufte-latex`, please note the slightly different syntax. I made the macros as similar to the usual LaTeX ones as possible. The manual offset is a postfix, e.g. `\sidenote[2]{foo}[10pt]` corresponds to `\footnote[2]{foo}` and there is `\sidenotemark` as well as `\sidenotetext`.

So far, it handles the semiautomatic mode (offset manually applied) very well and it works great with `marginfix` and a few marginals. However, it does not work well with full margins, `marginfix` and `\sidecaption`.

It would work great with `\blockmargin` back in `marginfix`, but I have to rephrase my own [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31734/marginfix-blockmargin) first, once I find time for that.

Comment: How has this package fared?

Comment: The package works well. There is documentation now as well. You can find the newest version on github (https://github.com/andythomas/TeX-sidenotes) an example thesis is here: http://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=2637968&fileOId=2637973