# mix marginnotes with marginpars without overlap

Tags: packages, marginpar

We are trying to put the figure caption as well as the footnotes in the margin and got very good results with the `tufte-latex` package. However, we have to manually adjust the offset of each sidenote or caption so that they do not overlap. Please see the following part of a page. Please note, how reference 64 was manually moved up to not be too close to the caption.

[image: thesis example page]

Now, we have to find something fully automatic and I found the `marginfix` package. It works great and can move `\marginpar`s around to get very pleasing results. Please see [this article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98hicks.pdf) how it works. I tried to make the [sidenote package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) to combine the look with the automatic feature.

Nevertheless, it is not useful to move a figure caption away from the adjacent figure. Therefore, the caption is placed with a `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package. If the margin gets very crowded, the `\marginpar`s start to overlap with the `\marginnote`s.

It seems, that was addressed in the first version of `marginfix`. I could 'block' some part of the margin with `\blockmargin`. Does anyone know why `\blockmargin` was dropped in the rewrite of `marginfix`? I asked the author, but got no response. The repository of `marginfix` is [here](https://github.com/shicks/marginfix).

Or is there another way to 'forbit' some area of the margin for `\marginpar`?

I tried a MWE to generally demonstrate the problem. Please replace the filename in the `\includegraphics` macro.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=260pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 
\marginpar{This could be a couple of references and other sidenotes.}
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. 
\marginpar{This could be a couple of references and other sidenotes.}
Pellentesque habitant morbi tris- tique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\marginpar{This could be a couple of references and other sidenotes.}
Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. 

\begin{figure}[h]
\marginnote{This would be where the caption should be.}
\includegraphics{broken_loop}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Please provide version numbers and dates. I wrote to S. Hicks end of July 2010, someday then he published a first version of marginfix, there were bug reports (I wrote one end of August 2010) and then he published version 0.9.1. To which rewrite do you refer?

Comment: I never used the old version with `\blockmargin`, but I found the command in the TUGboat article (http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98hicks.pdf). In the github repository (https://github.com/shicks/marginfix/commits/master/) it is present in the initial commit (Jun 23, 2010) and was dropped in the next one (Aug 8, 2010). I use marginfix extensively and it works great. Now I want to mix it with figure captions that require `\marginnote`, those obviously overlap with the `\marginpars`. `\blockmargin` would be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest to edit your question: Draft a minimal working example showing your need for a command blocking the margin, refer to the version of marginfix including \blockmargin and ask for somebody to code it. BUT from my own experience with marginfix I doubt that this will work, if not done with care. Marginfix moves marginnotes vertically. How should that be done in case of \blockmargin on the page? Probably you either have to cease using marginfix or captions in the margin.

Comment: @KeksDose: I did edit and we do indeed use captions under the figure instead of in the margin for now.

Comment: So is it accurate to say that you want side-captioned figure but without using `tufte-book` class?

Comment: @cmhughes: Can you provide an answer that shows an example with `tufte-class`?

Comment: You can also use the margincap environment of the mcaption package instead of marginnote. This do not prevent really overlapping with previous margin notes, but optionally allow the align of caption at the bottom of the image, and then this problem must be unusual.

Answer (score 4):

If the figure is a float, my first feeling is to allow to the figure float in a more fine place than "`h`ere", that is saturated of margin notes.

When the image must be just "`h`ere", a manual option is to adjust the alignment caption, for example using a`margincap` environment of the `mcaption` package or using `SCfigure` environment of the package `sidecap` with normal caption (which can be aligned with `\sidecaptionvpos`).

But for a general solution to prevent any posible overlapping of the side caption with preceedings `\marginpar` notes (with some extra separation), simply convert the caption in a  `\marginpar` note, using  `\figcaption`  (of package `captdef`), but outside of the float (that you can omit safely  in this case).

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=260pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{captdef}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 
\marginpar{This could be a couple of references and other sidenotes.}
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. 
\marginpar{This could be a couple of references and other sidenotes.}
Pellentesque habitant morbi tris- tique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\marginpar{This could be a couple of references and other sidenotes.}
Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. 

\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{\figcaption{
This would be where the caption should be.}}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{broken_loop}
\end{figure}

% or simply
% \marginpar{\figcaption{...}}
% \noindent\includegraphics{broken_loop}    

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```