# Where can one find old versions of packages released through CTAN?

Tags: packages, ctan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Historical, stable version archive of packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31886/historical-stable-version-archive-of-packages)

Is it possible to find a list of downloadable archives for older versions packages released through CTAN? For example, each package entry on the Comprehensive R Archive Network,

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html

has an "Old sources" link that leads to a page offering archives of every version of the package that was ever released:

http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tikzDevice/

I poked around on ctan.org for a few minutes but nothing jumped out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Historical, stable version archive of packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886/5764)

Comment: Agreed. An exact duplicate. The `historic` section of the TUG site is close enough to what I am looking for. And many thanks to Martin Scharrer for starting a dedicated archiving effort.