# Is there a way to revert manually to earlier versions of a package?

Tags: packages, ctan, obsolete

Is there a way to revert manually to earlier versions of a package?
I know this is a bit weird but I need previous versions of some packages for some reason.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31886/historical-stable-version-archive-of-packages

Comment: Depends how you installed it: for example, which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: Possible use case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256591/9075

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using TeXLive, `tlmgr` can backup installed versions (it already does this automagically) and restore previously installed; see [its documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html). I don't know if MikTeX offers something similar. And the [mercurial repository of CTAN](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/) offers older versions - but you'll have to install them manually.

If you use `tlmgr`, you can run `tlmgr restore [pkg]` to find what backups exists. If you have a version you want to restore to, run `tlmgr restore [pkg] [revision number]` to actually do the restoration.

Answer (score 8):

Historical versions of (some) packages were kept on an [Automated Mercurial Repositories of CTAN](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/) which has since been taken down. The most recent available version is available on [Wayback Machine - The Internet Archive (dated Oct 5, 2016)](https://web.archive.org/web/20161005173910/http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de:80/). However, you'll have to manually install these in your local `/texmf` folder.

Answer (score 5):

A repository of CTAN package versions would be very useful but it appears this 'Automated Mercurial Repositories' is no longer available.

Note: Automated Mercurial Repositories host http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de no longer appears to be registered.