# Problem with \addkey as of v4.08 of glossaries

Tags: glossaries

Having run TeX Live Utility today, glossaries was updated to the 30-July-2014 version (4.08). With this, a bug seems to have been introduced to the `\addkey` feature (run under both XeLaTeX and LuaTeX).

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt,twoside,one column,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[bookmarks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue,breaklinks=true, pdftitle={KKF},pdfauthor={KGF},unicode]{hyperref}    
\usepackage[toc,xindy]{glossaries}

% Define "ic" key:
\glsaddkey*
  {ic}% key
  {\glsentrytext{\glslabel}ic}% default value
  {\glsentryic}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
  {\Glsentryic}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
  {\glsic}% command analogous to \glstext
  {\Glsic}% command analogous to \Glstext
  {\GLSic}% command analogous to \GLStext

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossfile}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT HERE
\begin{document}
\Gls{syllable} becomes \glsic{syllable}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Glossfile contains the following:

```
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{syllable}{%
name={syllable},
ic={syllabic},
description={TO BE DEFINED}
}
```

The output now contains 'Syllable becomes @gls@user@icsyllabic' rather than 'Syllable becomes syllabic'.

Any ideas as to what happened? I did want to revert to the previous version of the package to make sure the fault lay in the update, and read details at [Is there a way to revert manually to earlier versions of a package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52915/is-there-a-way-to-revert-manually-to-earlier-versions-of-a-package) but didn't make any headway with it.

Comment: I have filed a bug report on this item. Those who wish to monitor it may do so at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&key=64.

Comment: Interim workaround: if the built-in keys user1..user6 haven't been used, replace the key in question with one of those. However, note that in the glossary file, the format is `user1={whatever}` whereas in the tex source, the commands are `\glsuseri{key}`. In other words, the suffixed numbers 1..6 must be replaced with lowercase Roman numberals, i, ii, etc.

Comment: According to an updated bug report received just now, this has been fixed as of version 4.09, which should become available shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerunning the MWE given above shows that the bug has indeed been addressed. Updating the package to version 4.09 will avoid the problem.