# Troubles with eso-pic package, later to update MiKTeK 2.9

Tags: watermark, eso-pic

I have a `.tex` document in which I use the logo of the research center as watermark. In order to insert this watermark, in my LaTeX file I always add the `eso-pic` package. In the past, I had never had problems with watermarks in my documents.  But recently, I had to do maintenance of my LaTeX distribution (MiKTeX 2.9) and I used the option of “Update MiKTeX (Admin)”. In the Updateable Packages window, I selected all the packages which required to be updated. All the updated process was successful. Later of updating the packages, I tried to compile my `.tex` file with TecXnicCenter 2.02 (32B), the output profile that I used was `Latex->pdf`.

The compilation process was aborted and I got the error message:
*pdflatex> ! LaTeX Error: File ‘eso-pic.sty’ not found.*

I checked the folder Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex and I found that `eso-pic` folder has the `showframe.sty` file. So, my sistem has the `eso-pic` package.

Now, I have the `eso-pic` version 2.0f and before, I had the 2010/10/06 v2.0c of this package.

I have reviewed the `.log` file in order to understand why MiKTeX can’t find the `eso-pic.sty` file, but I haven’t had success to figure out this problem. I also tried to review my `.tex` file to detect some mistake, but my code is right. Even I can’t get the pdf file with these lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}                
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}   
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
            \put(0,0){
            \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{onu.png}%
            \vfill
    }}}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}
bla,bla,bla
\end{document}
```

Any idea about to figure out this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Does it have the `eso-pic.sty` file? That is the package file TeX is looking for - not `showframe.sty`.

Comment: The question should be posted to the MiKTeX mailinglist as this issue appears when you have updated MiKTeX yesterday.

Comment: Sounds as if miktex made a packaging error and didn't include eso-pic.sty. That happens and is easily corrected -- if someone bother to tell the miktex maintainer that there is a problem. So make a bug report at the miktex site https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/?source=navbar.

Comment: Hi @cfr, definitely the folder eso-pic should have the `eso-pic.sty` and not only `showframe.sty`. I’m aware of that. For this reason, I believe that my problem is related with the update version of MiKTeX. Thanks for your commentary.

Comment: Hi @koppor and @ulrike-fischer. You are right about my problem is related to MiKTeX has problems to eso-pic package. Yesterday, later of googling I understood that MiKTeX Package Manager is not loaded the right way the `eso-pic` package, because the `eso-pic.sty` file is not on its folder. For this reason, I tried to install manually this package and I couldn’t compile the `eso-pic.dtx` file. I will report this `eso-pic` bug to MiKTeX. Thank you @koppor and @ulrike-fischer for their commentaries

Comment: For tracking: the sf.net bug is https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2381/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, I used basic-miktex-2.9.4250. so, I try to replace the name "showframe.sty" with "eso-pic.sty".

following this link http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/ms/contrib/eso-pic.sty then do like this MikTex Options > Refresh FNDB and Update format.

If it does not work, I suggest you to update your packages from MixTex Update Wizard and repeat again.

Comment: Hi Ryan,

It works your trick! Additionally, I did a little test: I tried to compile the eso-pic.dtx (in a temporal folder) and now MiKTeX can make the eso-pic.sty. Definitely the upgrade version of MiKTeX has a bug.

Again, thanks Riyan!

L.

Comment: @riyan and/or @luke - can you please clarify the step at `following this link`? I'm assisting another user in resolving this issue but I cannot personally reproduce it, so I can't experiment with different steps (e.g. should I paste the text at the URL into `texworks` and save it as `eso-pic.sty` in `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\eso-pic`? Or should `showframe.sty` be renamed?) The `eso-pic.sty` file contents on my machine (working) is different than the text at the link. Any clarification is much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It works your trick! 
Additionally, I did a little test: I tried to compile the `eso-pic.dtx` (in a temporal folder) and now MiKTeX can make the `eso-pic.sty`. Definitely the upgrade version of MiKTeX has a bug.

Again, thanks Riyan!

In order to use eso-pic package, later of I updated MiKTeX 2.9, I did the next procedure (Riyan's trick but with more details) :

1. I deleted all the text into `showframe.sty` (I let opened the file). Probably, in Windows XP and MiKTeK 2.9, the path of this folder would like be `C:\PROGRA~1\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\eso-pic`

Next step is considering that you cannot get the `eso-pic.sty` file, because the compilation of `eso-pic.dtx` file fails. The idea of this step is that you can get the `eso-pic.sty` file of anywhere and once that you get the file, you move the  `*.sty` to the eso-pic folder, where MiKTeX will try to find the `eso-pic.sty` file.

2. I wrote in Google `eso-pic.sty` and I found the script in: http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/ms/contrib/eso-pic.sty (this is the link that Riyan recommends in his answer). I selected all the text which has the page of this link and I pasted it in `showframe.sty` file, which was opened. I saved the file.
3. I renamed the `showframe.sty` file to `eso-pic.sty` file.
4. In a temporal folder, I downloaded the eso-pic package from Comprehensive Tex Archive Network (CTAN). I unzipped the file and I cut the files: `showframe.sty`, `eso-pic.ins` and`README`. Then, I pasted these files in eso-pic folder.
5. In Windows: Start -> Programs -> MiKTeX2.9 -> Maintenance -> Settings
6. In MiKTeX Options windows in General, you need to use first the button “Refresh FNDB” and later, push the button “Update Formats” and that’s it.