# Error resulting from hyperref-cleveref-ntheorem interaction: No counter '[' defined

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, ntheorem

I am on a Linux system running [TeX Live 2023](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) installed manually (not through the distro's repo), and up to date at the time of this writing (2023-04-21).

The following short document has started erroring after the most recent upgrade:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\title{}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{lemma}
  
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Specifically, the error I receive is

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: No counter '[' defined.
```

It goes away under any of the following circumstances:

1. I comment out `\usepackage{hyperref}`
2. I comment out `\usepackage{cleveref}`
3. I move `\usepackage{cleveref}` *above* `\usepackage{ntheorem}`

I would like to use all three packages, so that 1. and 2. aren't really fixes. As for 3., it too has drawbacks: if it loads before `ntheorem`, `cleveref` seems to lose track of environment types when cross-referencing: `\Cref{blah}` always produces `Lemma <blah>` even if `<blah>` was something else (theorem, proposition, definition, etc.).

This is not happening on other systems I have access to (still Linux, still `TeX Live 2023`), which update their respective `TeX Live` distributions more rarely. I distinctly remember `hyperref` received a very recent upgrade that may have introduced this.

**Edit**

I have followed the advice in one of the comments below to roll back `hyperref`. Since I did not immediately how to do this, I am recording that here (per [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52917/193209) other answer):

One first lists abvailable versions to revert to:

```
$ tlmgr restore hyperref
Available backups for hyperref: 65758 (2023-04-21 17:23)
```

and then, to actually effect the restoration:

```
$ tlmgr restore hyperref 65758
Do you really want to restore hyperref to revision 65758 (y/N): y
```

This will do fine for now: the file compiles all right on this earlier version of the package.

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm that this issue arises in a fully up-to-date MacTeX2023 distribution as well. Since neither `ntheorem` nor `cleveref` have received an update of late, a change in `hyperref` (which was updated most recently on Apr 20, i.e., just two days ago) may be the source of the issue. Note that I'm *not* going as far as calling it a "bug".

Comment: I will look later today.

Comment: grr, I forgot that cleveref redefines \refstepcounter to use an optional argument (and then redefines ntheorems \@thm to inject that). I will send a fix to ctan later today or tomorrow, for now at best use the backup option of tlmgr to revert to the previous hyperref version.

Comment: Thanks! The reversion suggestion worked fine. I have edited the original post to spell out how to do this, for anyone who might find their way here (I was unaware of the reversion capability myself; have never had to do it).

Comment: I have uploaded a new version which should fix that. Sorry.