# Why should I update my tex installation?

Tags: texlive, mactex, updating

Apart from not being able to get the latest package-updates, what are the benefits of the 2013 distribution over the one from 2012? Why should I update? I'm afraid updating will break something regarding my workflow with ST2 and synctex.

I haven't found a specific changelog regarding the update. Please enlighten me.

Comment: The [`Present`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-810009.2) section of the TeX Live Guide should give you some pointers.

Comment: In fact, the complete [`Release history`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-700009) is another useful resource.

Comment: @cgnieder or, if you want to, please provide an answer, and I'll delete my comments.

Comment: Did you use to update your packages when you were working with TeX Live 2012? If so, then I would suggest updating to TeX Live 2013. If not, then you can still update, and revert back selectively to older versions of packages that work. See [Historical, stable version archive of packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886/5764).

Comment: Breaking something should not be a major concern, as you can easily install the 2 distributions next to each other. I myself always keep the old one, just in case :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, was pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MacTeX project has written a nice [summary of changes](http://tug.org/mactex/newfeatures.html) in MacTeX 2013, including a detailed list of changes in TeX Live 2013 (compared to 2012).

They also link to the reference [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#news) changes page, as indicated in comments below your answer.