# Algorithm2e Comment Lines w/out semicolons

Tags: algorithm2e

For some reason even when I enable `\DontPrintSemicolon` there are still semicolons on lines with comments. This is in Algorithm2e version 3.9.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lined,boxed]{algorithm2e}% using version 3.9
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\DontPrintSemicolon}[0]{\dontprintsemicolon}%remove for 5.0

%define defaults for algorithm2e
\let \oriAlgorithm=\algorithm
\renewcommand{\algorithm}[2]{
  \oriAlgorithm  % Begin document
    \SetLine
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwComment{Comment}{}{}
    \Titleofalgo{ #1 }
    \caption{ #2 }
}

\newcommand*{\Set}[2]{ #1 $\gets$ #2 }
\newcommand*{\SetC}[3]{ #1 $\gets$ #2 \Comment*[r]{#3} }

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}{test}{test to show semicolons existence}
    \SetC{$f$}{$true$}{Some comment}\;
    \Set{$f$}{$\lnot f$}\;
    \Return{$f$}\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled latex png]

Comment: Why don't you update to [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) version 5.0? The only [historic stable version](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886/5764) available is [`algorithm2e` 4.01](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/algorithm2e.html). If you're *stuck* with using `algorithm2e` 3.9, you should make that available somewhere (usually [`Pastebin`](http://www.pastebin.org)).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: It's the package in tex-science on debian, so it would just be a pain to upgrade. Are you confirming that this was a bug in previous releases? And what do you mean regarding your link to pastebin (make what available)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bug in an outdated version of a package. This bug has been fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

5.0 documentation states a bug was fixed regarding this issue,

> a bug with side text -- text put into () -- of command macro (SetKwIf
>   and so on) which was always setting a ’;’ even after a
>   \DontPrintSemicolon

Comment: You can literally just download [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty) and place it in your working folder. Simple as that.