# Online service to compare different versions of TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, online, backward-compatibility

I’ve been wondering if there is any online service which allows one to compile a document using different versions of TeX Live (2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, …) and compare the result.
I’m imagining something like [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) (web development) or, to a lesser extent, [ideone](https://ideone.com/) (general programming) for TeX.

I often find myself wishing that something like this existed when comparing document output between different versions of TeX Live or finding out when a bug in a certain package was introduced/fixed.
However, having so many different full installations of TeX Live side by side is not something that is easy to set up or maintain.
So, is there another solution that allows comparing different versions of TeX Live quickly?

Comment: Related: [Historical, stable version archive of packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886/5764)

Comment: Historical versions of TeX Live: [TUG FTP](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/)

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it's hard to have different TL versions set up: I have every one since TL'09 on my laptop. However, 'TeX Live version' is a rather imprecise thing to use for tracking _package_ bugs: it's only _engine binaries_ that are fixed. For individual packages, the version can change throughout the year.

Comment: @JosephWright It’s hard in the sense of requiring continuous manual maintenance, a lot of time for the initial setup and a lot of disk space. What I was thinking of were the “frozen” versions of TeX Live at the end of the year.

Comment: @Socob Well yes you need a bit of disk space, but the effort is pretty minimal once you get things set up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but for further reference: on Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/ you can select the system used to compile a project, and it proposes texlive versions dating back to 2014.

Comment: It’s not perfect, since it’s not entirely clear what is included in those versions (e. g. there are two versions of TeX Live 2016, namely “2016 (Overleaf v1) (Legacy)” and “2016 (ShareLaTeX) (Legacy)”), but still very useful – thanks!