# Download old versions of RevTeX

Tags: packages, revtex, ctan

I am trying to compile a very old document (c. 1995) which used `\documentstyle[aps,eqsecnum,prc]{revtex}` -- is there anywhere I can download such a style file?

Comment: Welcome. // Can you contact REVTeX? https://journals.aps.org/revtex  , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REVTeX

Comment: you could get a 1995 tex distribution, but it's probably easier just to adjust the document to work with a current revtex

Comment: You can review older versions of `revtex` here: https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/?view=log

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Historical, stable version archive of packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would probably be REVTeX 3. REVTeX 3.1 (c. 1996) can be found at http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex209/contrib/revtex.zip,   and while written for LaTeX2.09 the README gives instructions for running under LaTeX2e as it was back in the 1990s, these may well no longer work on a current system.

Old TeX Live versions are available through https://tug.org/historic/ and the [1996 TeX Live ISO](https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/1996/) may do the job (and probably contains REVTeX 3.1).

[REVTeX 4.0](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-0) (c. 2000) is also obsolete now, but contains instructions for moving from REVTeX 3.1 to REVTEX 4.0 at http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/revtex4-0/differ.tex (it appears to exist online in compiled form in a few random places turned up by search engines). In theory any REVTeX 4.0 document should then run on the latest REVTeX 4.2 on a recent TeX Live.

Of course depending on what other packages and macros are used within the document there may be other (REVTeX-independent) issues compiling on a more recent distribution.