# Is there a way to prevent marginpars colliding with tabs created using the fancy tabs package

Tags: marginpar, fancytabs

I am automatically creating large documents that use fancytabs as thumb marks and that also use marginpar notes to convey information about the text. (I actually put them in a Tikz lozenge since fancytabs has loaded tikz anyway - see example). The problem is that often in a few hundred page document the marginpar will collide with the fancytab. It is going to be hugely time consuming if I have to shift them manually.

I can work out where on a page the fancy tab is going to appear and as per the example its easy to manually shift the marginpars. I can't work out how to determine where (vertically) the marginpar will appear. Marginpar also takes care to make sure the margin notes don't collide with each other, but I am struggling to work out how to stop the marginpars colliding with the tabs.

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Here is a short working example

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancytabsWidth{3cm}

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][anchor=center]{%
\oldmarginpar{
     ~\\ % Need this, rather strangely, to get the tikz node to anchor properly.
     \tikz \draw node (one) [] at (0,0) {}  node (two) [anchor=north,text     width=2.0cm,draw,align=left,text badly ragged,fill=black!05,rounded corners,#1] at   (0,0) {\baselineskip=-2pt ~\\#2 \\ } ;      }
      }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\fancytab{fancy tab}{2}
\textbf{Some more text which will contain a little margin note, the problem being that the margin note collides with the fancy tab that we have created. Is there a way to get the margin note to shift down below the tab}
\marginpar{This note collides}
\marginpar[yshift=-2cm]{This one has been manually shifted out the way}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: example collision render]

Comment: There is a related question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31734/mix-marginnotes-with-marginpars-without-overlap). I would expect, that there is no solution, yet, as well. The author of `marginfix` is [working](https://github.com/shicks/marginfix) on it. Look for `phantom` or `blockmargin` in the documentation. I have not tried it in a while.

Comment: Thanks, I did have a go with marginfix, but the latest version causes the colliding tab to disappear. Still the fact that its doing something may give me the "in" I need.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer: adjust the value of `\fancytabsWidth` as a fraction of the parameter `\oddsidemargin`:

```
\fancytabsWidth{0.75\oddsidemargin}
```

This will place the tab apart and let a white of `0.25\oddsidemargin`between the marginpar and the tab. Eventually you may need to adjust the size of the font used inside the tab.

[image: Exemplo sem colisão]

This is not the *vertical* solution you wanted, but I think it is the most elegant and disrupting. It does not work however, when you set a layout where the `oddsidemargin` is too thin.

Comment: there's a serious problem with this when a book is printed and bound -- the final step is physically trimming the bound pages to the final size, and if the thumb tabs are too narrow there's a real danger that they will be cut off.

Comment: Unfortunately its not going to work for a lot of the documents. The thumb tabs need to carry some information with the current design (upto about 6 words), which will make them too long. Also with the 800 page+ documents, I will need to fit in about 24 tabs and if they are too "long" they will cycle round an awful lot of times.