# Hook for outer par mode

Tags: floats, etoolbox

Is it possible to execute macros after the correct mode is 'reached?'

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{marginfix}

\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{\AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\marginpar{#1}}}
%\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{\AfterBackInOuterParMode{\marginpar{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \begin{center}
   My figure goes here
   \caption[Caption for LOF]{bar\mymarginpar{A note}}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
   \centering
   my table goes here
   \caption[Caption for LOF]{bar\mymarginpar{Another note}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also considered a simple if/elseif detection of the environment, i.e. figure or table, but in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39738/command-behavior-depending-on-current-environment) question it is already discussed, how nested environments will not work. The first example is called in a `center` not `figure` environment?!

My naïve idea idea would be some kind of `\AfterBackInOuterParMode`. Is it possible to achieve this?

-- EDIT:

People ask to use MWEs in questions so I tried to do that. However, why other solutions can not be considered gets lost this way. So, here is a little bit of background: In a template (we made) to generate PhD theses or lecture notes, there are two most common complaints.

One of them is the (disability) to use [sidenotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) in captions, which is quite common if you utilize them for the references as well. In the end, it looks [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35071/8631). You can also see, why any kind of manual adjustment (offset etc.) is out of the question, since two or more output files (one for a kindle) are generated from the same input file. `marginnote` cannot be used, because we use `marginfix`. Otherwise, the notes will overlap. This causes all kind of issues, one of them described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31734/mix-marginnotes-with-marginpars-without-overlap).

The `\begin{center}` was only added to exemplify nested environment. If I detect the actual (inner) environment, I would get `center` and not `figure`.

In total, is there a way to define `mymarginpar` such that is works in the MWE?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining what your end goal is here? A `\marginpar` is a float just like `figure` and thus it cannot be used from here. But `\marginnote` from the package of the same name can, so why not just use that.

Comment: Unrelated: yuo should never center a figure using the `center` env. It adds vertical space as does the `figure` env. Replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and delete `\end{center}`

Comment: Even if one were to add some environment detection that would do the same for `table` as for `figure` in the example, the marginal note could be on quite a different page from the figure or table. Is it really wanted? `\marginnote` as suggested by @daleif sounds like a better idea, otherwise probably the OP should better explain how the whole should behave (IOW, this could be an XY problem).

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I tried to clarify the question (which makes it not so MWEish).

Comment: What's the problem in using `marginnote` along with `marginfix`?

Comment: @egreg: The notes overlap.

Comment: It's hard to guess what you would want `\AfterBackInOuterParMode` to do, the caption at no point is processed in outer par mode so you could detect that and so avoid the error by not making the marginal note but I don't think that is what you want)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am looking for something that does `\AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\marginpar{#1}}` in a figure environment and `\AfterEndEnvironment{table}{\marginpar{#1}}` in a table environment. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39738/command-behavior-depending-on-current-environment) @egreg explained why and how it fails if the environments are nested. So, I was hoping for something that can even detect the 'outer' figure. Does that make sense?