# Sidenotes and marginnotes change color when hyperlinks break over a line in tufte-latex

Tags: hyperref, tufte, sidenotes

When using the `tufte-book` or `tufte-handout` document class, if a sidenote or marginnote is placed on a line that ends with a hyperlink which continues onto the next line (i.e. the hyperlink breaks over the end of the line), then the sidenote/marginnote takes on the coloring of the link.

The MWE below shows this behavior. Shortening the long links so that they no longer break onto the next line removes the coloration from the corresponding marginal material.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}

Here is my label.\label{label}

This\sidenote{this is colored} \hyperref[label]{is a very very very very long link that breaks onto the next line}.

This\sidenote{this is not} \hyperref[label]{is a short link}.

This\marginnote{this is colored} \hyperref[label]{is a very very very very long link that breaks onto the next line}.

This\marginnote{this is not} \hyperref[label]{is a short link}.

\end{document}
```

[image: tufte-latex and hyperref colored marginalia]

How can I prevent marginal material from taking on the link color in this situation?

Comment: Did you try this with another document class?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how I would implement this in another document class since the `\sidenote` and `\marginnote` commands are provided by `tufte-latex`. The `sidenotes` package provides similar functionality, but I do not believe it is loaded by the `tufte-latex` document classes.

Comment: Why do you not load `sidenotes` package directly. I think it can be used independently from the class ?

Comment: If I change the document class to `article` and load `hyperref` and `sidenotes` the problem does not occur. However, that might be a separate issue since I don't know if the `\sidenote` command provided by `tufte-latex` is the same as the one provided by the `sidenotes` package as [tufte-latex predates sidenotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25444/combining-tufte-handout-with-classicthesis-article?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The described behavior looks like a bug. As a workaround you can set the color for the side- and marginnotes explicitly:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\setsidenotefont{\color{black}\footnotesize}   <-- set the color and font here
\setmarginnotefont{\color{black}\footnotesize} <-- and here

\begin{document}

Here is my label.\label{label}

This\sidenote{this is colored} \hyperref[label]{is a very very very very long link that breaks onto the next line}.

This\sidenote{this is not} \hyperref[label]{is a short link}.

This\marginnote{this is colored} \hyperref[label]{is a very very very very long link that breaks onto the next line}.

This\marginnote{this is not} \hyperref[label]{is a short link}.

\end{document}
```

This gives you plain black side- and marginnotes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've notified the maintainers of the issue.