# How to fix hyperlink spilling in tufte footnote when word wrapping?

Tags: footnotes, tufte, links, sidenotes, href

I am using the tufte-book class and I noticed a weird behavior of the footnotes. Here is the setting, there is a line of text with a footnote on it and the last word wraps to the next line, then:

- If I try to make the last word a link with \href, the link will have a hit box that spans the whole width of the text below the first line.
- If I try to color the last word, all of the footnote will be colored. (This was resolved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199797/sidenotes-and-marginnotes-change-color-when-hyperlinks-break-over-a-line-in-tuft))

Here is a minimal example with a screenshot (you can't see my cursor, but it was hovering right below 'will') of the behavior on my pdf viewer.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\begin{document}

There\footnote{This is a footnote} will be a long link \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{here is a very long link that breaks over to the next line}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following patch. It assumes that you use pdflatex and it requires a current texsystem. The command used is quite new.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@addmarginpar{\hb@xt@}{\pdfrunninglinkoff\hb@xt@}{}{\fail}
\apptocmd\@addmarginpar{\pdfrunninglinkon}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pdfborder=1 1 1,urlbordercolor=red} % to show the link
There\footnote{This is a footnote}
will be a long link \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{here is a very long link that breaks over to the next line}.
\end{document}
```

### Output without the patch

[image]

### Output with the patch

[image]