# Hyperlink from previous citation appears in footnote and heading

Tags: hyperref

the hyperref of a previous in-text citation appears also in the following footnote including the site number and the heading of the following page. I am super confused.

Thanks,
Sebastian

[image: Hyperref error]

Comment: it can happen, it is a side effect of the feature that pdftex can break links over lines. In a new tex system one can interrupt such links, see  e.g https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/2388 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623616/2388.

Comment: Thank you. command looks as the following: \citeA{barth2017}.\footnote{...}. Hence, the problems appears to come from the fact that the footnote follows the in-text citation; deleting the in-text citation solves the issue (but inconsistently not deleting the footnote)

Comment: the problem is that there is a page break in the middle of the citation. But without a complete example it is not possible to test solutions.