# How to adapt classic thesis layout to print standards?

Tags: margins, classicthesis

I'm writing my thesis with `classic thesis` and I need to make some changes to the layout. I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22248/change-margins-in-classicthesis?rq=1) some suggestions that suit my needs. But I have to change the seize of the right margin in order to set the number of the chapter at about 1 inch. Despite of the fact that it's not in the original classic thesis project, can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: Don't use `classicthesis`, then

Comment: @egreg : ...then, any suggestion of a thesis template with those margins?

Comment: @AndrewCashner And so do we about Tikz, KOMA-script, and Oh! LaTeX.  I agree with egreg though - why would one use classicthesis and make it ugly by reducing the margin to 1".

Comment: ...because I love classic thesis even if a stupid directive that doesn't care of any aesthetic and typographic questions squeezes me to write a very short thesis. Too complicated to explain. I found this and it's pretty nice:\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Analogue to the comments before:
`\usepackage[a4paper, text={160mm,240mm}, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm, bindingoffset=1.5cm,top=27mm]{geometry}`
(these were my last settings) and its adaptions always did the job for me.
There are far more ways to use it, the whole explanation of the `geometry` package is to be found [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf).